# VBA Error - Type MisMatch

Tags: sql, vba

I don't know why Excel - VB is behaving stupidly. My tool has several user forms. Everything was working fine until I renamed a command button's caption. I am getting a Type miss-match error. The command loads another form. The form_initialise code is below. when I commented out all of the code the code in userform_initialise it works fine, but when remove the comment ' from all the lines it give me an error Type Mismatch.

Earlier it was working perfect and my company is using it as well. Can anyone help.

```
  Private Sub UserForm_initialize()


  lstUser.AddItem Sheets("LAUNCH").Range("Z1").Value

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim conn As Object
  Dim rs As Object
  Dim objMycmd As Object
  Dim rc As Long
  Dim sConnString As String
    ' Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=XXXXXXXX;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;" & _
                  "Integrated Security=XXXXXXXX;" & _
                  "User ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;" & _
                  "Passsword=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;"
   ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString



    Sql = "Select DISTINCT [Exec] from tblKPI3"
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open Sql, conn, adOpenStatic

    If rs.EOF Then
        MsgBox "No Records"
    Else
        rs.Movefirst
        If Sheets("LAUNCH").Range("AA1") = "Yes" Then
        With frmReport.lstUser
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem rs![exec]
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop Until rs.EOF
        End With
        End If
    End If


    rs.Close
    conn.Close
   end sub
```

Comment: Alex, can you help here please. I am try to open an old version of the tool. All the excel files are now giving the same error. I dont know why.

Comment: Which lines gives the error ?